# Hair particle rendered unlike in the materiel preview, it looks clumpy

Tags: rendering, hair

i'm not familiar with blender, and having some problems with hair particle. Hair look just fine when it's in material preview, but it looks different in rendered preview. The hair is clumping like one big hair.
This is rendered preview ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1JiB.jpg
This is material preview ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZpEd.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: you need to adjust the Diameter value in the Hair Shape section. See linked question